# Can I redirect the HTTP request towards an old folder to the homepage using .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, apache2, webserver

I  have to following situation: I had an old blog that was made using Joomla (this blog was indexed well enough by search engines). For some problems I delete it and I have create it again using WordPress.

Now I have many visit (from Google) that leading to specific pages of the old site (pages that don't exist in the new version).

For example I have visit to URL as: `/scorejava/index.php/corso-spring-mvc/1-test` that don't exist on my new site.

I would know if using the *.htaccess* file (or other sistem) I can redirect the HTTP request directed to some subfolder (that don't exist in the new version) to the homepage of my new site.

For example I have the request towards the void URL: `/scorejava/index.php/corso-spring-mvc/1-test`.

And I would create a regular expression that say something like: all the request toward the subfolder `corso-spring-mvc` (and all it's content file and subfolder) have to be redirected to `www.scorejava.com`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*/corso-spring-mvc/ [R=301,L]
```

The regular expression can be pretty much anything. Whatever matches will be redirected to the root of your site, represented by `/` and the browser will get a 301 permanent redirect.

Now, I suspect you should try a more generic rule, otherwise you'll have a lot of them to write. If the old blog was under `/scorejava/*` for example, then you only need a rule like:

```
RewriteRule ^/score_java/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: mmm the base URL (that now is in use) is scorejava.com.

Simply I would map some specific subfolder (as /corso-spring-mvc) that have to be redirected toward the base URL. I would toward all the request to all the files in these specific subfolder (they arent mutch...only 3-4 subfolder) but the important thing is that the request to the resources in these subfolder are redirect

Comment: Normally you redirect the page and resources are requested for the *new* page, in this case your home page. Are you saying there are direct links to resources too?